How to pivot a table in snowpark python
I have a table in snowflake with the following structure and stored in a snowpark dataframe df
as
user pref Model
A   1     BMW
A   2     Mercedez
B   1     Volvo
B   2     VW
C   1     Toyota
C   2     BMW
D   1     Jaguar

what i am looking for from the pivot operations is to transform the above into
User_id  Pref_1 Pref_2
A        BMW    Mercedez
B        Volvo  VW
C        Toyota BMW
D        Jaguar NULL


Dynamic pivot or lateral flatten in Snowflake / Snowpark to columns

This question is similar to: Dynamic pivot or lateral flatten in Snowflake / Snowpark to columns. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
